# Add Array elements to String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm creating a game of hangman, and long story short, is there a shortcut of sorts to put this array of separate strings together into a string other than doing like below?

```
String after = under[0] + under[1] + under[2] + under[3] + under[4] + under[5] + under[6] + under[7] + under[8] + under[9] + under[10] + under[11] + under[12] + under[13] + under[14] + under[15] + under[16] + under[17] + under[18] + under[19] + under[20] + under[21];
```

Comment: ever heard of loops ?

Comment: If you can pull in an extra library, [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has a StringUtils class that will let you do this `String after = StringUtils.join(under, '');`.

Comment: @Bartdude Hey, that's not nice... People do not hear about loops right away. I learned about loops when I got tired of typing the same code ten to fifteen times, changing a digit or two each time :):):)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight > Sorry if it seems rude... i'm maybe to new to SO but  I didn't see it as an introduction to programming. I also don't find this question acceptable as we could discuss on which type of loop to use, not seeing the surrounding code of this line, and he doesn't describe a problem but ask on how to do this or that...

Comment: I have while loops and a few for loops throughout my code, mostly for guess-checking. I had never heard of StringBuilder as many people have suggested, or even thought of using the go-around boomz suggested on Strings. The code around it, I would think, is irrelevant, as I'm just looking for something less tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a loop, like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0 ; i != 22 ; i++) {
    sb.append(under[i]);
}
String after = sb.toString();
```

You can also add strings to an initially empty string, but that's suboptimal, because all the intermediate strings get allocated and released in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Always use loop to perform repetitive operation like this.

Also, It is advised to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`. String in JAVA is immutable.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int nCount = 22;

for (int iCnt = 0 ; iCnt <= nCount ; iCnt++) {
    sb.append(under[iCnt]);
}
String after = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
String after = "";

for (int i=0; i<22; i++)
    after += under[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not shorter, but is less tedious:

```
StringBuilder afterBldr = new StringBuilder();
for (String underEl : under) {
     afterBldr.append(underEl);
}
String after = afterBldr.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) library, use the [`join()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) method, it's the nicest solution:

```
String str = StringUtils.join(under, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) can be used here.

```
Joiner.on("").join(names)
```